# How can I use Facebook Javascript SDK within a browser extension?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use the Facebook JS SDK within a browser extension/sidebar. I've seen other questions about this, but no specific answers. I don't want to do separate OAuth handling - I'd prefer to use the JS SDK which makes this all transparent.

However, it seems that the FB.* calls never fire their callbacks at all. Am I missing something? Is it even possible to use the JS SDK within a non-hosted environment?

Example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXX',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : false
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        alert('CALLBACK');
    });
};
```

Thanks,

Matt Kruse

Comment: Did you in firefox addon? You shouldn't have the issues that were mentioned below with google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [this blog post](http://everythingxaml.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_24.html)

> Unfortunately, Facebook JavaScript SDK doesn’t work on a Chrome
>   Extension because it is working under “chrome-extension://” protocol.
>   While Google provides a tutorial for OAuth, Facebook explains a
>   slightly easier way.

[Facebooks OAuth/login explanation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/#client-side-flow)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the invisible iFrame technique posted here: http://brianmayer.com/2012/12/building-a-chrome-extension-that-connects-to-a-facebook-app/

But it seems like a lot of work.